# SKAction group doesn't execute with runBlock

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to run a group where there is an animation and a method running together. I am repeating it forever but the method is not getting executed

```
SKAction *animation1 = [SKAction animateWithTextures:texturesSnakeShoot timePerFrame:0.2];


SKAction *group = [SKAction group:@[animation1, [SKAction runBlock:^{

    [self shootProjectileFrom:spotty.position to:
     CGPointMake(-10, spotty.position.y)];
}]]];

[spotty runAction : [SKAction repeatActionForever:group]];
```

the method is getting called only once and animation is repeating. Why is that?

Comment: How do you know that? Did you put a breakpoint into the block?

Comment: no i didn't but the action that needs to be performed by shootProjetileFrom method in the run block is not executing. The projectile that it needs to shoot is happening only once.

Comment: I put a breakpoint as you suggested but the method shootProjectileFrom is being called only once.

Comment: If you add the runBlock to a SKAction sequence with a small delay, it will work in a group. However, I suggest you replace the runBlock with a performSelector:onTarget action or move the code to the update method.